# DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0

Tags: ios, cordova, cookies, phonegap-build

I have a phonegap app that just was approved for pre-flight ios. There were some mysterious goings with initial testing where the splash screen stayed up indefinitely. I manually took it away using:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
setTimeout(function() { 

    navigator.splashscreen.hide(); 

}, 3000);
```

However, I think I just cured a symptom of a larger problem. Now when we test in the emulator we see:

DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/Girri/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/82C299C6-BCB0-4EDE-A9B5-8C7A2DB3811D/data/Containers/Data/Application/1C7B7A8B-1F8A-401A-9B8B-FEA1DD68277F/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies

...and accounts cannot be created in the app. Somehow I think it's related to my icons and splash screens but not sure how.

Comment: Are you using Phonegap Build or the CLI version?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was able to fix the problem once I reloaded phonegap and the platform. Who knows what was going on. Also, I don't believe this is a problem on the actual device, which is what I was really worried about. Thanks for trying to help.